# how do i get x path for for a logout button in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get XPath in selenium webdriver for logout button of a webpage.

here's the a ref tag

```
<a href="https://www.freecrm.com/index.cfm?logout=1" class="topnavlink"><i class="fa fa-sign-out icon-2x"></i> &nbsp; Logout &nbsp; </a>
```

can you help

Comment: Could you give the url? In chrome you can right click on an element when you inspect and click copy xpath

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click the **Logout** button you can use either of the following line of code :

- **`Java - cssSelector`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.topnavlink[href='https://www.freecrm.com/index.cfm?logout=1'] > i.fa.fa-sign-out.icon-2x")).click();
  ```
- **`Java - xpath`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='topnavlink' and contains(@href,'https://www.freecrm.com/index.cfm?logout=1')]/i[@class='fa fa-sign-out icon-2x']")).click();
  ```

Comment: What is the point of using empty italic node as target for a click?

Answer (score 0):

I would get it this way:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'logout')]
```

Or better, use css selector:

```
a[href*=logout]
```